# the overload resolution of using base member function introduced into derived class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using-declaration

According to some quotes in standard:
[[over.match.funcs]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#4)

> [...] For non-conversion functions introduced by a using-declaration into a derived class, the function is considered to be a member of the derived class for the purpose of defining the type of the implicit object parameter.

And consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Base {
    void show(double) {
        std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct Test :Base {
    using Base::show;  //#1
    void show(double) { //#2
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    Test t;
    t.show(1.2);
}
```

According to the standard I cited,it means that take a implict object parameter of type `Test` as that of  `#1`.
For `#1`,the declaration would be `show(Test&,double)`.
For `#2`,the declaration would be `show(Test&,double)`.
so in the purpose of overload resolution,the each implicit conversion sequence of `#1` is indistinguishable with that of `#2`,the invocation of `t.show(1.2)` would be ambiguous,however `#2` is called,why? if I miss something in the standard,please correct me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Test::show(double)` has the same signature with the `Base::show(double)`; it just *hides* the one from the base class.

For [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition),

(emphasis mine)

> If the derived class already has a member with the same name, parameter list, and qualifications, the derived class member **hides or overrides (doesn't conflict with)** the member that is introduced from the base class.

From the standard, [[namespace.udecl]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#14)

> When a using-declarator brings declarations from a base class into a
>   derived class, member functions and member function templates in the
>   derived class override and/or hide member functions and member
>   function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list
>   ([dcl.fct]), trailing requires-clause (if any), cv-qualification, and
>   ref-qualifier (if any), in a base class (rather than conflicting).
>   Such hidden or overridden declarations are excluded from the set of
>   declarations introduced by the using-declarator. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct B {
>   virtual void f(int);
>   virtual void f(char);
>   void g(int);
>   void h(int);
> };
>
> struct D : B {
>   using B::f;
>   void f(int);      // OK: D​::​f(int) overrides B​::​f(int);
>
>   using B::g;
>   void g(char);     // OK
>
>   using B::h;
>   void h(int);      // OK: D​::​h(int) hides B​::​h(int)
> };
>
> ...
> ```